# "Parse Error: Header overflow" During Node.js GET Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to submit a form through Google forms programmatically through a `GET` request, but I am receiving the error `Parse Error: Header overflow`.

I output the debug code to the following:

```sh
REQUEST {
  uri: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/viewform',
  callback: [Function],
  method: 'GET'
}
REQUEST make request https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/viewform
REQUEST onRequestResponse https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/viewform 200 {
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'x-robots-tag': 'noindex, nofollow, nosnippet',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  expires: 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
  date: 'Tue, 27 Aug 2019 11:05:58 GMT',
  p3p: 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info.", CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  server: 'GSE',
  'set-cookie': [
    'NID=188=p7faYHOB1ZQttXneuG5V7K-LXg3zH638MWT4zoW2Gwl69z8To4AjIFZh0ZSifiGKZk7XMk910-ChZjKyRxLcIzu5RaHzgw9HA9YArnFLtS8ov0-FxCaSCuFzTNR1DxT3WNH3_jsleeHRy2lRKzn5yjGpFihQhDGoLAJMqj9naLY; expires=Wed, 26-Feb-2020 11:05:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly',
    'NID=188=M3LrQ0mUfSz8fPBiN0vamDQ9sIE1FfZjwrN599Q0NlWXy1yc3ssj6iNU59TMO5MbbTBXgnGv333gwtGBzACo_GJKTvFWoBv5EbjOGWSZ9DwuITjHEXjh7X9Pw6Y2E8bC7_NR1rQpyfoZfjV4ScxLFVYn2Da8f6CPT2zvW9iD614; expires=Wed, 26-Feb-2020 11:05:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly',
    'S=spreadsheet_forms=zyDFpNN-66y1kRpAoOFdWvNuV20NyyyA; Domain=.docs.google.com; Expires=Tue, 27-Aug-2019 12:05:58 GMT; Path=/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg; Secure; HttpOnly'
  ],
  'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"',
  'accept-ranges': 'none',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  connection: 'close'
}
REQUEST reading response's body
REQUEST finish init function https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/viewform
REQUEST response end https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/viewform 200 {
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'x-robots-tag': 'noindex, nofollow, nosnippet',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  expires: 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
  date: 'Tue, 27 Aug 2019 11:05:58 GMT',
  p3p: 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info.", CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  server: 'GSE',
  'set-cookie': [
    'NID=188=p7faYHOB1ZQttXneuG5V7K-LXg3zH638MWT4zoW2Gwl69z8To4AjIFZh0ZSifiGKZk7XMk910-ChZjKyRxLcIzu5RaHzgw9HA9YArnFLtS8ov0-FxCaSCuFzTNR1DxT3WNH3_jsleeHRy2lRKzn5yjGpFihQhDGoLAJMqj9naLY; expires=Wed, 26-Feb-2020 11:05:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly',
    'NID=188=M3LrQ0mUfSz8fPBiN0vamDQ9sIE1FfZjwrN599Q0NlWXy1yc3ssj6iNU59TMO5MbbTBXgnGv333gwtGBzACo_GJKTvFWoBv5EbjOGWSZ9DwuITjHEXjh7X9Pw6Y2E8bC7_NR1rQpyfoZfjV4ScxLFVYn2Da8f6CPT2zvW9iD614; expires=Wed, 26-Feb-2020 11:05:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly',
    'S=spreadsheet_forms=zyDFpNN-66y1kRpAoOFdWvNuV20NyyyA; Domain=.docs.google.com; Expires=Tue, 27-Aug-2019 12:05:58 GMT; Path=/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg; Secure; HttpOnly'
  ],
  'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"',
  'accept-ranges': 'none',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  connection: 'close'
}
REQUEST end event https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/viewform
REQUEST has body https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/viewform 250879
REQUEST emitting complete https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/viewform
REQUEST {
  url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/formResponse',
  qs: {
    'entry.1685503023': 'Completely Agree',
    'entry.1114836796': 'Agree',
    'entry.1357049422': 'Agree',
    'entry.86605751': 'Agree',
    'entry.472640154': 'Agree',
    'entry.578340154': 'Agree',
    'entry.1342145939': 'Agree',
    'entry.908476553': 'Agree',
    'entry.1767728649': 'Agree',
    'entry.261135357': 'Agree',
    'entry.955881343': 'Agree',
    'entry.644828648': 'Agree',
    'entry.1389259807': 'Agree',
    'entry.1119338533': 'Agree',
    'entry.1062429863': 'Agree',
    'entry.516860473': 'Agree',
    'entry.567444201': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.482251296': 'Agree',
    'entry.498646145': 'Agree',
    'entry.1560601161': 'Agree',
    'entry.1444586702': 'Agree',
    'entry.922754460': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.1557835370': 'Agree',
    'entry.467854058': 'Agree',
    'entry.1589546710': 'Agree',
    'entry.2108902598': 'Agree',
    'entry.281144796': 'Agree',
    'entry.1530873848': 'Agree',
    'entry.1424024691': 'Agree',
    'entry.1731945609': 'Agree',
    'entry.907193508': 'Agree',
    'entry.1153672983': 'Agree',
    'entry.580562563': 'Agree',
    'entry.1831284314': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.1993591785': 'Agree',
    'entry.2006331742': 'Agree',
    'entry.1827982714': 'Agree',
    'entry.993541708': 'Agree',
    'entry.1391636956': 'Agree',
    'entry.91447117': 'Agree',
    'entry.114054349': 'Agree',
    'entry.1479669058': 'Agree',
    'entry.169007299': 'Agree',
    'entry.1674987636': 'Agree',
    'entry.781409566': 'Agree',
    'entry.1715842899': 'Agree',
    'entry.2122555380': 'Agree',
    'entry.1839860132': 'Agree',
    'entry.1798162602': 'Agree',
    'entry.534974595': 'Agree',
    'entry.1915445764': 'Agree',
    'entry.1620257977': 'Agree',
    'entry.1081230217': 'Agree',
    'entry.1830529504': 'Agree',
    'entry.898930382': 'Agree',
    'entry.1192389256': 'Agree',
    'entry.151544055': 'Agree',
    'entry.349843311': 'Agree',
    'entry.1121996014': 'Agree',
    'entry.1257519461': 'Agree',
    'entry.2041168852': 'Agree',
    'entry.1448317082': 'Agree',
    'entry.822017211': 'Agree',
    'entry.2070207179': 'Agree',
    'entry.1294073322': 'Agree',
    'entry.1350554776': 'Agree',
    'entry.331473110': 'Agree',
    'entry.1872389749': 'Agree',
    'entry.1316304979': 'Agree',
    'entry.1757255400': 'Agree',
    'entry.1067906573': 'Agree',
    'entry.470696499': 'Agree',
    'entry.1626751662': 'Agree',
    'entry.1276689933': 'Agree',
    'entry.1113634309': 'Agree',
    'entry.1155614358': 'Agree',
    'entry.1958637973': 'Agree',
    'entry.470332824': 'Agree',
    'entry.392453027': 'Agree',
    'entry.1589198700': 'Agree',
    'entry.1949725356': 'Agree',
    'entry.849004808': 'Agree',
    'entry.161553396': 'Agree',
    'entry.586309661': 'Agree',
    'entry.936612705': 'Agree',
    'entry.1122630561': 'Agree',
    'entry.1928824068': 'Agree',
    'entry.548688753': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.1889668025': 'Agree',
    'entry.432775722': 'Agree',
    'entry.443111614': 'Agree',
    'entry.1021968621': 'Agree',
    'entry.1203098592': 'Agree',
    'entry.2144723307': 'Agree',
    'entry.1915333401': 'Agree',
    'entry.1894339866': 'Agree',
    'entry.645054929': 'Agree',
    'entry.206646349': 'Agree',
    'entry.1650858765': 'Agree',
    'entry.82078653': 'Agree',
    'entry.1371169995': 'Agree',
    'entry.271214876': 'Agree',
    'entry.410917678': 'Agree',
    'entry.1192455003': 'Agree',
    'entry.1661631785': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.578250942': 'Agree',
    'entry.33974948': 'Agree',
    'entry.1087544379': 'Agree',
    'entry.610072221': 'Agree',
    'entry.1196285049': 'Agree',
    'entry.399911317': 'Agree',
    'entry.1339798463': 'Agree',
    'entry.1139777018': 'Agree',
    'entry.1253745912': 'Agree',
    'entry.1018082058': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.618305883': 'Agree',
    'entry.1673555985': 'Agree',
    'entry.69524582': 'Agree',
    'entry.751997319': 'Agree',
    'entry.1688009496': 'Agree',
    'entry.1878671812': 'Agree',
    'entry.1628966265': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.1131585981': 'Agree',
    'entry.865622826': 'Agree',
    'entry.839910403': 'Agree',
    'entry.329075391': 'Agree',
    'entry.797122277': 'Agree',
    'entry.51198863': 'Agree',
    'entry.814847401': 'Agree',
    'entry.1292307698': 'Agree',
    'entry.249345051': 'Agree',
    'entry.1347230989': 'Agree',
    'entry.1823033486': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.1997754411': 'Agree',
    'entry.1943812633': 'Agree',
    'entry.2068211302': 'Agree',
    'entry.1848471308': 'Agree',
    'entry.908441447': 'Agree',
    'entry.1003990001': 'Agree',
    'entry.718684127': 'Agree',
    'entry.392810795': 'Agree',
    'entry.947249041': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.1454952975': 'Agree',
    'entry.1143227505': 'Agree',
    'entry.1246226991': 'Agree',
    'entry.1613073769': 'Agree',
    'entry.632378461': 'Agree',
    'entry.1934717828': 'Agree',
    'entry.1744297141': 'Agree',
    'entry.3576454': 'Somewhat Agree',
    'entry.482058093': 'Agree',
    'entry.1314940116': 'Agree',
    'entry.254955372': 'Agree',
    'entry.1190333749': 'Agree',
    'entry.596033500': 'Agree',
    'entry.1953426485': 'Agree',
    'entry.1446585381': 'Agree',
    emailAddress: 'user@example.com',
    submit: 'Submit',
    usp: 'pp_url',
    fvv: '1',
    pageHistory: '0,1,2,3,4',
    fbzx: '3268431771106696425'
  },
  useQuerystring: true,
  callback: [Function],
  method: 'GET'
}
REQUEST make request https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/9dSLQpIAF1L8TGy0CqiMX6_KOTQ3sgw-iTbnXLw7qQ73L03WSk9wrmUg/formResponse?entry.1685503023=Completely%20Agree&entry.1114836796=Agree&entry.1357049422=Agree&entry.86605751=Agree&entry.472640154=Agree&entry.578340154=Agree&entry.1342145939=Agree&entry.908476553=Agree&entry.1767728649=Agree&entry.261135357=Agree&entry.955881343=Agree&entry.644828648=Agree&entry.1389259807=Agree&entry.1119338533=Agree&entry.1062429863=Agree&entry.516860473=Agree&entry.567444201=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.482251296=Agree&entry.498646145=Agree&entry.1560601161=Agree&entry.1444586702=Agree&entry.922754460=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.1557835370=Agree&entry.467854058=Agree&entry.1589546710=Agree&entry.2108902598=Agree&entry.281144796=Agree&entry.1530873848=Agree&entry.1424024691=Agree&entry.1731945609=Agree&entry.907193508=Agree&entry.1153672983=Agree&entry.580562563=Agree&entry.1831284314=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.1993591785=Agree&entry.2006331742=Agree&entry.1827982714=Agree&entry.993541708=Agree&entry.1391636956=Agree&entry.91447117=Agree&entry.114054349=Agree&entry.1479669058=Agree&entry.169007299=Agree&entry.1674987636=Agree&entry.781409566=Agree&entry.1715842899=Agree&entry.2122555380=Agree&entry.1839860132=Agree&entry.1798162602=Agree&entry.534974595=Agree&entry.1915445764=Agree&entry.1620257977=Agree&entry.1081230217=Agree&entry.1830529504=Agree&entry.898930382=Agree&entry.1192389256=Agree&entry.151544055=Agree&entry.349843311=Agree&entry.1121996014=Agree&entry.1257519461=Agree&entry.2041168852=Agree&entry.1448317082=Agree&entry.822017211=Agree&entry.2070207179=Agree&entry.1294073322=Agree&entry.1350554776=Agree&entry.331473110=Agree&entry.1872389749=Agree&entry.1316304979=Agree&entry.1757255400=Agree&entry.1067906573=Agree&entry.470696499=Agree&entry.1626751662=Agree&entry.1276689933=Agree&entry.1113634309=Agree&entry.1155614358=Agree&entry.1958637973=Agree&entry.470332824=Agree&entry.392453027=Agree&entry.1589198700=Agree&entry.1949725356=Agree&entry.849004808=Agree&entry.161553396=Agree&entry.586309661=Agree&entry.936612705=Agree&entry.1122630561=Agree&entry.1928824068=Agree&entry.548688753=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.1889668025=Agree&entry.432775722=Agree&entry.443111614=Agree&entry.1021968621=Agree&entry.1203098592=Agree&entry.2144723307=Agree&entry.1915333401=Agree&entry.1894339866=Agree&entry.645054929=Agree&entry.206646349=Agree&entry.1650858765=Agree&entry.82078653=Agree&entry.1371169995=Agree&entry.271214876=Agree&entry.410917678=Agree&entry.1192455003=Agree&entry.1661631785=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.578250942=Agree&entry.33974948=Agree&entry.1087544379=Agree&entry.610072221=Agree&entry.1196285049=Agree&entry.399911317=Agree&entry.1339798463=Agree&entry.1139777018=Agree&entry.1253745912=Agree&entry.1018082058=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.618305883=Agree&entry.1673555985=Agree&entry.69524582=Agree&entry.751997319=Agree&entry.1688009496=Agree&entry.1878671812=Agree&entry.1628966265=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.1131585981=Agree&entry.865622826=Agree&entry.839910403=Agree&entry.329075391=Agree&entry.797122277=Agree&entry.51198863=Agree&entry.814847401=Agree&entry.1292307698=Agree&entry.249345051=Agree&entry.1347230989=Agree&entry.1823033486=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.1997754411=Agree&entry.1943812633=Agree&entry.2068211302=Agree&entry.1848471308=Agree&entry.908441447=Agree&entry.1003990001=Agree&entry.718684127=Agree&entry.392810795=Agree&entry.947249041=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.1454952975=Agree&entry.1143227505=Agree&entry.1246226991=Agree&entry.1613073769=Agree&entry.632378461=Agree&entry.1934717828=Agree&entry.1744297141=Agree&entry.3576454=Somewhat%20Agree&entry.482058093=Agree&entry.1314940116=Agree&entry.254955372=Agree&entry.1190333749=Agree&entry.596033500=Agree&entry.1953426485=Agree&entry.1446585381=Agree&emailAddress=user%40example.com&submit=Submit&usp=pp_url&fvv=1&pageHistory=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4&fbzx=3268431771106696425
Error: Parse Error: Header overflow
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:456:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17) {
  bytesParsed: 9276,
  code: 'HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW',
  reason: 'Header overflow',
  rawPacket: <Buffer 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 33 30 32 20 4d 6f 76 65 64 20 54 65 6d 70 6f 72 61 72 69 6c 79 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 74 65 78 74 ... 10439 more bytes>
}
```

I know there's a limit of 80Kb with Node, but I don't think I'm reaching it. I don't know why it's getting so big. I pasted the GET link in Chrome and it worked fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you said there is an <strike>80Kb</strike> 8Kb header size.`node --max-http-header-size 15000 index.js`.

edit:- due to some vulnerabilities`(CVE-2018-12121 and CVE-2018-12122)` the header size has been changed from 80kb to 8kb. [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24731)

Comment: Even if it is hitting the limit, I'd like to know why, and how I can lower it, because it doesn't make sense to me that it's hitting the limit. It worked fine until recently. I wish to debug to know what went wrong.

Comment: You checked if it works with the flag ?, if it works we know that the limit is the problem, so we can start thinking for a solution.

Comment: Apparently they changed the limit from 80kb to 8kb. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for finding it useful, i will update my answer with that info.